# Use \MakeUppercase on output of \newcommand

Tags: macros, uppercase

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\deftitle}[1]{%                                                                                                                                                                                 
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Aa}}{aaa}{}%                                                                                                                                                                         
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Bb}}{bbb}{}%                                                                                                                                                                         
}%                                                                                                                                                                                                          

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase sffdfd

\MakeUppercase \deftitle{Aa}
\end{document}
```

While `\MakeUppercase sffdfd` works impeccably, `\MakeUppercase \deftitle{Aa}` results in an error. How to apply `\MakeUppercase` on the output of `\newcommand`?

Comment: First: You'd have to put braces around the argument. Second: `\ifthenelse` isn't expandable!

Comment: `\MakeUppercase sffdfd` yields `Sffdfd`: is that what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup fails because `\MakeUppercase` will grab one argument, and if you don't use braces this will be the first token it sees. That first token in your code is `\deftitle`. In the next step `\MakeUppercase` tries to expand its argument as far as possible, but since it got grabbed without the argument to `\deftitle` this will fail! The correct way would be to first expand `\deftitle` with its argument, and then apply `\MakeUppercase` to the first character that this results in. This can't be done without changes to your setup.

The following assumes that your `\deftitle` can actually work being fully expandable (which is true for your MWE).

---

The code here might be very unstable depending on input (works well for `\deftitle` producing ASCII-output). See below for something which is better.

Since `\ifthenelse` isn't expandable, you can't directly use it to produce your desired results. Because of this, the following defines two tests (doing it like this instead of loading a package defining all the tests just for educational purposes).

The first test is a test for an empty argument (`\myifempty`). It works by first turning the argument into a string and then comparing it to `\relax` using `\if`. If the argument isn't empty `\relax` will be compared by a character of category other and hence result in false. If it is empty `\relax` will be compared with the second `\relax` and result in the test being true.

The second test compares two strings (`\myifeq`) and results in true if they are indeed the same. For this I use the package `pdftexcmds` to get the macro `\pdf@strcmp` also in engines which don't have it as a built-in.

The next thing we need is a macro which fully expands the input before handing it over to `\MakeUppercase`. For this I use an `\edef` expansion and check whether the result is empty with `\ifx\mytmp\@empty`. Afterwards `\MakeUppercase` gets the first token of the full expansion in `\mytmp` as its argument.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myifempty[1]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\myifeq[2]
  {%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\ExpandAndUppercaseFirst[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \edef\mytmp{#1}%
      \unless\ifx\mytmp\@empty
        \expandafter\MakeUppercase\mytmp
      \fi
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatletter

\newcommand\deftitle[1]
  {%
    \myifeq{#1}{Aa}{aaa}{}%
    \myifeq{#1}{Bb}{bbb}{}%
  }

\begin{document}
\ExpandAndUppercaseFirst{\deftitle{Aa}}
\end{document}
```

---

The same macro, but way more stable, using the `expl3` programming layer:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ExpandAndUppercaseFirst { m }
  {
    \text_titlecase_first:n { #1 }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \deftitle { m }
  {%
    \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { Aa } { aaa }
    \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { Bb } { bbb }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExpandAndUppercaseFirst{\deftitle{Aa}}
\end{document}
```